# teradata locking table for access sql equivalent

Tags: sql, teradata

In teradata we have 'LOCKING TABLE TABLE_NAME FOR ACCESS'. What's the equivalent of ACCESS in SQL.

```
ROW SHARE
ROW EXCLUSIVE
SHARE UPDATE
SHARE
SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE
EXCLUSIVE
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as the `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint in SQL Server.

On a session level it's `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` in both Teradata and SQL Server.

Comment: I should have added Oracle there as well. Do you know what the equivalent in Oracle DB is?

Comment: There's no equivalent in Oracle. Oracle people will tell you that you don't need it, because readers don't block writers (and that's usually true).